# Div image link resize relative to page resize

Tags: html, css

Here are a few pics that demonstrate my problem.

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

[image: 2]

Most of this page by area is a background image. There are 4 image links. 3 around the middle, and one at the top left.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href= "CSS/main.css">
</head>

<body>

   <div class = "tips">
      <a href="tips.html">
        <img src="Images/TipsLink.png" alt="Tips">
      </a>
   </div>

   <div class = "anchor">
      <a href="anchor.html">
       <img src="Images/PrintAnchorButton.png" alt="Anchor">
      </a>
   </div>

   <div class = "launch">
       <a href="launch.html">
         <img src="Images/LaunchAppButton.png" alt="Launch">
       </a>
   </div>

   <div class = "camera">
       <a href="camera.html">
          <img src="Images/PointCameraButton.png" alt="Camera">
       </a>
   </div>    
</body>
</html>
```

These are simple links represented by images. Very straightforward.

I changed their positions using CSS. The background-image should scale with different screen resolutions, and so should the images. The images links fail to 1) resize, and 2) reposition.

```
html{

   position: relative;
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
   background-image: url("../Images/WebsiteBackground22.png");
   background-size: 100%;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
}


body{

}

.anchor {
    position: absolute;
    top: 37%;
    left: 17%;
}

.tips {
    position: absolute;
    top: 3%;
    left: 6%;
}

.launch {
    position: absolute;
    top: 65%;
    left: 39%;
}

.camera {
    position: absolute;
    top: 37%;
    left: 65%;
}   

I thought that putting the absolutely positioned image links inside the relative positioned body would allow the overall page to scale depending on screen size, and then the image links would scale with the page but they would also have set positions. This did not work as shown in the images.
```

My goal is for the images to scale with the page so that a small page has the same proportions as the first image I posted. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You need to make the images responsive themselves. Something along the lines of `img { display: block; max-width: 100%; height: auto; }`. Along with giving their container a percentage width. Personally I'd use a CSS grid framework to obtain your layout vs absolute positioning.

Comment: I used those commands on the image and gave the body container a width of 100%. Nothing changed though

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by _"the body container."_ Here's a [basic demo](https://jsfiddle.net/v2d3ws7b/).

Answer (score 0):

```
img {
    display: block;
max-width: 100%;
height: auto;
vertical-align: middle;
}
```

try this, and avoid absolute position with multiple images in screen

Comment: Assign class to images